# 'someone of X' is derogatory?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I read a news [here](http://in.reuters.com/article/pope-motherteresa-idINKBN0U10YG20151218?feedType=RSS&feedName=globalCoverage2&google_editors_picks=true) that says:

> Mother Teresa ***of Calcutta*** to be made a saint

Now my question is: We all know Mother Teresa very well. To my mind, there is no other Mother Teresa who has done a similar type of work for humanity. So, is it necessary to write 'of Calcutta' after her name? Can't we write:

> Mother Teresa to be made a saint

I find 'of X' a derogatory remark for the third-world countries as if European Mother Teresa is no longer a European and she belongs to Calcutta. Maybe I sound a bit upfront here, but I would appreciate if natives will clear my doubts. My only concern is which type of writing style is this?

Comment: That thought didn't come to my mind when I scanned through your question (so what I saw was basically only quoted part). I think it sounded neutral because she was also known as *Blessed Teresa of Calcutta*.

Comment: And if/when she is made a saint, she will be "Saint Teresa", which there is already [five](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saint_Teresa). To keep them separate, it is necessary to have some way to tell them apart. So, she will likely be "Saint Teresa of Calcutta"...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As a native speaker, I wouldn't take this to be derogatory in the slightest. Typically when people are given an "of REGION" in a formal title, it's attaching a place that helps distinguishing the aforementioned individual.

> Lord Douglas of Hawick and Tibbers
>   Charles II of Scotland
>   etc...

The place mentioned doesn't have to be a birth place, but can be a place that has some significance to the individual for one reason or another. Apparently in this case, it's significant because a large portion of the work was carried out in or from Calcutta.

This system appears to be a an unofficial emulation of Official [Titles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peerage_of_the_United_Kingdom#Titles) in the United Kingdom, but I'd argue that this isn't necessarily the case, nor are Titles in the United Kingdom the origin of using such terminology. Take for example "Jesus of Nazareth", an ancient example of this. In this case, adding "Of Nazareth" could help people determine just which Jesus is being referred to, since it was a fairly common name.

I suppose it's possible to abuse this system into an insult, but I can't think of any such examples and even if I could I don't think they'd be appropriate. What I can clearly say is that this is in no way an insult.

Answer (score 4):

As a native speaker I see no insult intended in referring to  Mother Theresa as 'of Calcutta'.

1. Presumably Mother Theresa felt a great affection for Calcutta during her lifetime.  I assume she would not see the title as insulting.
2. It is common to extend a person's name as a sign of respect or status (eg Saint Thomas the Apostle, Prince William the Duke of Cambridge etc)
3. There will be a necessity to distinguish this Saint Theresa and the others (google turns up St Teresa of Avila, St Terese of Lisieux, St Theresa of the Andes and others).

You may or may not be aware that Teresa was not her name given at birth but was selected for religious reasons.  [This link](http://anunslife.org/resources/nun-sister-religious-name) has very brief information about the selection of the religious name.  For this reason the use of her surname would not be appropriate to distinguish her and another form must be found.

Also the presence of a [memorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memorial_House_of_Mother_Teresa) shrine built to honour her in her home town indicates that your thoughts about her not being considered European are incorrect.

tl:dr  **No insult intended.  This form is a sign of respect and necessary for practical reasons also.

Answer (score 3):

This is a common style for Catholic saints. St. Teresa de Avila, St Therese Liseaux, St Francis of Asissi, St Augustine of Hippo, and many others. Part of it is that there are so many saints that the clarification is needed, and then once it had been used for many saints, it became a badge of honor, that you represent that place in the line of saints.

Answer (score 1):

It's not derogatory at all. Indeed, many surnames in the English-speaking world are derived either from the person's occupation (Smith, Baker, Cooper, ...) or directly from place names ([Washington](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Washington,_Tyne_and_Wear#George_Washington_connection), [Lincoln](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lincoln,_England), ...). In this case, "of Calcutta" isn't a surname but the fact that people use place names as surnames shows that it's not derogatory.

Answer (score 0):

it's not derogatory, nor has it anything to do with her nativeness or migration. I'll take you to *this style* step-by-step!

> According to a biography written by Joan Graff Clucas, in her early years Agnes was **fascinated by stories of the lives of missionaries and their service in Bengal,** and by age 12 had become convinced that she should commit herself to a religious life. Her final resolution was taken on 15 August 1928, while praying at the shrine of the Black Madonna of Vitina-Letnice, where she often went on pilgrimage...

then...

> She arrived in India in 1929, and began her novitiate in ***Darjeeling (Bengal)***, near the Himalayan mountains

serving for 20 years...

> She took her solemn vows on 14 May 1937, while serving as a teacher at the Loreto convent school in Entally, eastern ***Calcutta***. Teresa served there for almost *twenty years* and in 1944 was appointed headmistress.
>
> ...medical training in the Holy Family Hospital and then ventured out into the slums. Initially, she started a school in Motijhil ***(Calcutta)***; soon she started tending to the needs of the destitute and starving....

working for needy

> Mother Teresa soon opened a home for those suffering from Hansen's disease, commonly known as leprosy, and called the hospice Shanti Nagar (City of Peace). The Missionaries of Charity also established several leprosy outreach clinics **throughout Calcutta,** providing medication, bandages and food...

She helped poorest among poor and her entire life, she dedicated in serving human lives **in Calcutta**. Though her humanitarian work had no limits, her majority of such great work was quite limited to **the region of Calcutta.**

Indeed the are **no two Mother Teresas** but because of her excellent and pure work *in and around* Calcutta (today's Kolkata), it goes pretty well like that. In Hinduism it is known as ***Karmabhoomi***. Great souls can even make places (they worked throughout their lives) great. Thus, places' names are then attached to their names.

One more example that you, being an Indian, might understand well include:

> *Sabarmati's saint* -it has **nothing** to do with [Mahatma's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahatma_Gandhi) birthplace and nativeness

Good question!

---

[Source: Mother Teresa on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mother_Teresa)

Comment: I think the OP already knows about her life. Also, the assertion "there are no two Mother Teresas" is not correct, IMHO.

Comment: I don't buy your opinion! @DamkerngT. And it's *important* to show Mother's relationship with the city and region.

Comment: There are about 540,000 Teresas in the USA. I would be surprised if there wasn't another "Mother Teresa".

Comment: There are 1 zillion mothers as well! @gnasher729 Does it matter?